# show the data from complex json data in php

Tags: php

Array
(
    [category] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [id] => 15
                    [parent] => 11
                    [name] => Albums
                    [slug] => albums
                    [img_url] => http://playcontest.in/diy/wordpress/wp-content/uploads/2013/06/cd_5_angle.jpg
                    [count] => 4
                    [link] => http://playcontest.in/diy/wordpress/product-category/music/albums/
                )

```
        [1] => Array
            (
                [id] => 9
                [parent] => 0
                [name] => Clothing
                [slug] => clothing
                [img_url] => http://playcontest.in/diy/wordpress/wp-content/uploads/2013/06/hoodie_6_front.jpg
                [count] => 12
                [link] => http://playcontest.in/diy/wordpress/product-category/clothing/
            )

        [2] => Array
            (
                [id] => 10
                [parent] => 9
                [name] => Hoodies
                [slug] => hoodies
                [img_url] => http://playcontest.in/diy/wordpress/wp-content/uploads/2013/06/hoodie_6_front.jpg
                [count] => 6
                [link] => http://playcontest.in/diy/wordpress/product-category/clothing/hoodies/
            )



    )

[meta_data] => Array
    (
        [tz] => Europe/London
        [c] => INR
        [c_f] => ?
        [t_i] => 
        [w_u] => lbs
        [d_u] => in
        [d_s] => .
        [t_s] => ,
        [p_d] => 2
        [c_p] => left
        [cart_url] => http://playcontest.in/diy/wordpress/cart/
        [checkout_url] => http://playcontest.in/diy/wordpress/checkout/
        [hide_out_of_stock] => no
    )

[best_selling] => Array
    (
        [0] => Array
            (
                [stock] => 1
                [url] => http://playcontest.in/diy/wordpress/product/woo-album-4/
                [desc] => Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Vestibulum tortor quam, feugiat vitae, ultricies eget, tempor sit amet, ante. Donec eu libero sit amet quam egestas semper. Aenean ultricies mi vitae est. Mauris placerat eleifend leo.
                [title] => Woo Album #4
                [id] => 96
                [img] => http://playcontest.in/diy/wordpress/wp-content/uploads/2013/06/cd_5_angle.jpg
                [type] => simple
                [price] => 9
                [regular_price] => 9
                [sale_price] => 
                [category_ids] => Array
                    (
                        [0] => 15
                        [1] => 11
                    )

                [created_at] => 2013-06-07 11:37:23
                [average_rating] => 5.00
                [total_sales] => 23
                [featured] => 
            )

        [1] => Array
            (
                [stock] => 1
                [url] => http://playcontest.in/diy/wordpress/product/woo-single-2/
                [desc] => Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Vestibulum tortor quam, feugiat vitae, ultricies eget, tempor sit amet, ante. Donec eu libero sit amet quam egestas semper. Aenean ultricies mi vitae est. Mauris placerat eleifend leo.
                [title] => Woo Single #2
                [id] => 99
                [img] => http://playcontest.in/diy/wordpress/wp-content/uploads/2013/06/cd_6_angle.jpg
                [type] => simple
                [price] => 2
                [regular_price] => 3
                [sale_price] => 2
                [category_ids] => Array
                    (
                        [0] => 11
                        [1] => 13
                    )

                [created_at] => 2013-06-07 11:38:12
                [average_rating] => 4.50
                [total_sales] => 6
                [featured] => 
            )



    )

[new_arrivals] => Array
    (
        [0] => Array
            (
                [stock] => 1
                [url] => http://playcontest.in/diy/wordpress/product/woo-single-2/
                [desc] => Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Vestibulum tortor quam, feugiat vitae, ultricies eget, tempor sit amet, ante. Donec eu libero sit amet quam egestas semper. Aenean ultricies mi vitae est. Mauris placerat eleifend leo.
                [title] => Woo Single #2
                [id] => 99
                [img] => http://playcontest.in/diy/wordpress/wp-content/uploads/2013/06/cd_6_angle.jpg
                [type] => simple
                [price] => 2
                [regular_price] => 3
                [sale_price] => 2
                [category_ids] => Array
                    (
                        [0] => 11
                        [1] => 13
                    )

                [created_at] => 2013-06-07 11:38:12
                [average_rating] => 4.50
                [total_sales] => 6
                [featured] => 
            )

        [1] => Array
            (
                [stock] => 1
                [url] => http://playcontest.in/diy/wordpress/product/woo-album-4/
                [desc] => Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Vestibulum tortor quam, feugiat vitae, ultricies eget, tempor sit amet, ante. Donec eu libero sit amet quam egestas semper. Aenean ultricies mi vitae est. Mauris placerat eleifend leo.
                [title] => Woo Album #4
                [id] => 96
                [img] => http://playcontest.in/diy/wordpress/wp-content/uploads/2013/06/cd_5_angle.jpg
                [type] => simple
                [price] => 9
                [regular_price] => 9
                [sale_price] => 
                [category_ids] => Array
                    (
                        [0] => 15
                        [1] => 11
                    )

                [created_at] => 2013-06-07 11:37:23
                [average_rating] => 5.00
                [total_sales] => 23
                [featured] => 
            )

        [2] => Array
            (
                [stock] => 1
                [url] => http://playcontest.in/diy/wordpress/product/woo-single-1/
                [desc] => Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Vestibulum tortor quam, feugiat vitae, ultricies eget, tempor sit amet, ante. Donec eu libero sit amet quam egestas semper. Aenean ultricies mi vitae est. Mauris placerat eleifend leo.
                [title] => Woo Single #1
                [id] => 93
                [img] => http://playcontest.in/diy/wordpress/wp-content/uploads/2013/06/cd_4_angle.jpg
                [type] => simple
                [price] => 0.01
                [regular_price] => 0.01
                [sale_price] => 
                [category_ids] => Array
                    (
                        [0] => 11
                        [1] => 13
                    )

                [created_at] => 2013-06-07 11:36:34
                [average_rating] => 0.00
                [total_sales] => 3
                [featured] => 
            )



    )

[new_sales] => Array
    (
        [0] => Array
            (
                [stock] => 1
                [url] => http://playcontest.in/diy/wordpress/product/flying-ninja/
                [desc] => Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Vestibulum tortor quam, feugiat vitae, ultricies eget, tempor sit amet, ante. Donec eu libero sit amet quam egestas semper. Aenean ultricies mi vitae est. Mauris placerat eleifend leo.
                [title] => Flying Ninja
                [id] => 70
                [img] => http://playcontest.in/diy/wordpress/wp-content/uploads/2013/06/poster_2_up.jpg
                [type] => simple
                [price] => 12
                [regular_price] => 15
                [sale_price] => 12
                [category_ids] => Array
                    (
                        [0] => 12
                    )

                [created_at] => 2013-06-07 11:25:01
                [average_rating] => 4.00
                [total_sales] => 3
                [featured] => 
            )

        [1] => Array
            (
                [stock] => 1
                [url] => http://playcontest.in/diy/wordpress/product/premium-quality-2/
                [desc] => Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Vestibulum tortor quam, feugiat vitae, ultricies eget, tempor sit amet, ante. Donec eu libero sit amet quam egestas semper. Aenean ultricies mi vitae est. Mauris placerat eleifend leo.
                [title] => Premium Quality
                [id] => 73
                [img] => http://playcontest.in/diy/wordpress/wp-content/uploads/2013/06/poster_3_up.jpg
                [type] => simple
                [price] => 12
                [regular_price] => 15
                [sale_price] => 12
                [category_ids] => Array
                    (
                        [0] => 12
                    )

                [created_at] => 2013-06-07 11:27:38
                [average_rating] => 2.00
                [total_sales] => 1
                [featured] => 
            )

        [2] => Array
            (
                [stock] => 1
                [url] => http://playcontest.in/diy/wordpress/product/ship-your-idea-2/
                [desc] => Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Vestibulum tortor quam, feugiat vitae, ultricies eget, tempor sit amet, ante. Donec eu libero sit amet quam egestas semper. Aenean ultricies mi vitae est. Mauris placerat eleifend leo.
                [title] => Ship Your Idea
                [id] => 40
                [img] => http://playcontest.in/diy/wordpress/wp-content/uploads/2013/06/hoodie_7_front.jpg
                [type] => variable
                [price] => 30
                [regular_price] => 
                [sale_price] => 
                [category_ids] => Array
                    (
                        [0] => 9
                        [1] => 10
                    )

                [min_var_price] => 30
                [max_var_price] => 35
                [created_at] => 2013-06-07 11:00:28
                [average_rating] => 4.00
                [total_sales] => 0
                [featured] => 
            )



    )

[payment] => Array
    (
        [gateways] => Array
            (
                [0] => Array
                    (
                        [id] => cheque
                        [title] => Cheque Payment
                        [description] => Please send your cheque to Store Name, Store Street, Store Town, Store State / County, Store Postcode.
                        [icon] => 
                        [chosen] => 
                        [order_button_text] => 
                        [enabled] => yes
                        [testmode] => 
                        [instructions] => Please send your cheque to Store Name, Store Street, Store Town, Store State / County, Store Postcode.
                        [account_details] => Array
                            (
                            )

                        [settings] => Array
                            (
                            )

                    )

                [1] => Array
                    (
                        [id] => cod
                        [title] => Cash on Delivery
                        [description] => Pay with cash upon delivery.
                        [icon] => 
                        [chosen] => 
                        [order_button_text] => 
                        [enabled] => yes
                        [testmode] => 
                        [instructions] => Pay with cash upon delivery.
                        [account_details] => Array
                            (
                            )

                        [settings] => Array
                            (
                                [extra_charges] => 100
                                [extra_charges_msg] => COD Charges
                                [extra_charges_type] => amount
                                [cod_pincodes] => 12345,23456
                                [in_ex_pincode] => include
                            )

                    )

                [2] => Array
                    (
                        [id] => cop
                        [title] => Cash on pickup
                        [description] => Pay your order in cash as you pick it up at our store.
                        [icon] => 
                        [chosen] => 
                        [order_button_text] => Place order
                        [enabled] => yes
                        [testmode] => 
                        [instructions] => Pay with cash on pickup at [Store address].
                        [account_details] => Array
                            (
                            )

                        [settings] => Array
                            (
                            )

                    )


            )

    )
```

)

Comment: What exactly is your problem?

Comment: 1. please edit your question so that it get's readable (there is an `edit` linkk below your question, _use it!_). 2. what _exactly_ do you mean by "show data"? 3. what is your _specific_ question here?

Comment: Please show us the data you are working with and what you want to achieve

Comment: Parse the JSON Data fetched from http://playcontest.in/test/response.php and display the "new_arrivals" count.


i already fetched the data but difficulty for show the fetching data on out put page

Comment: this is my php code but i want show specific data need to me.
see below code

<?php 
   
  $json_url = "http://playcontest.in/test/response.php";
  $json = file_get_contents($json_url);
  $data = json_decode($json, TRUE);
  echo "<pre>";
  
  print_r($data);
  echo "</pre>";
    
   
   ?>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that the "new arrivals count" as you call it is the number of elements in the "new_arrivals" array, this works:

```
$data = json_decode( ... your json string ... );
echo count($data->new_arrivals);
```

**Edit:** It's really hard to understand what you want. How about this?

```
echo "<table><tr>";
foreach ($data["new_arrivals"][0] as $key => $value) {
    if ($key == "category_ids") continue;
    echo "<th>" . $key . "</th>";
}
echo "</tr>";
foreach ($data["new_arrivals"] as $row) {
    echo "<tr>";
    foreach ($row as $key => $value) {
        if ($key == "category_ids") continue;
        echo "<td>" . $value . "</td>";
    }
    echo "</tr>";
}
echo "</table>";
```

Comment: not like this type 

i want finally answer (should be show all data)

Comment: Can you give an example of the result you want?

Comment: Should be like below ....
 <table style="width:100%"> <tr> <th>id</th><th>stock</th> <th>url</th><th>description</th> <th>title</th><th>img</th><th>type</th> <th>price</th><th>regular_price</th><th>sale_price</th><th>category_ids</th><th>created_at</th><th>average_rating</th><th>total_sales</th><th>featured</th></tr>

should be display all records.. in loop wise

Comment: its some correct but not showing all data need mine .

please check my sent code

Comment: need to total count of   "" new_arrivals """

Comment: how to fetch total numbers of  ``new_arrivals`` plz reply quick

Comment: i guess you want `count($data["new_arrivals"])`